# Authorization token for twitchapi

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, retrofit2

I'm playing with TwitchAPI using retrofit. I want to get data games. Based on their docs, for apps get token they need to do [OAuth Implicit code flow](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/getting-tokens-oauth/#oauth-implicit-code-flow) initially. Doing this with retrofit I get an HTML as my response. This HTML is when the user will log in and authorize the app. After login I get my access token.

I've tried the [OAuth Client Credentials Flow](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/getting-tokens-oauth/#oauth-client-credentials-flow). Modifying my call to get token, I get a JSON object with all necessary infos.

```
@POST("token")
Call<AccessTokenResponse> getData(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headerMap, @Query("client_id")String clientId, @Query("client_secret") String clientSecret, @Query("grant_type")String grantType);
```

This type is to be used with server-to-server requests. But the response is perfectly valid.

I'm using implicit approach but i'm struggling with HTML response. I don't know how can I use it and get access token after user authorizes. what do I need to do to get access token properly?

My code:

```
@GET("authorize")
Call<String>getDataImplicit(@Query("client_id")String clientId, @Query("redirect_uri") String redirectUri, @Query("response_type") String responseType, @Query("scope")String scopeType, @Query("state")String state);
```

My call:

```
Call<String>getImplicit = HttpConnectionHandler.getInstance().getTwitchGameApi().getDataImplicit("my client id", REDIRECT_URI, "token", "analytics:read:games", "123qwerty");
        getImplicit.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if(response.code() != 200){
                    ResponseBody responseBody = response.errorBody();
                    try {
                        String str = responseBody.string();
                        Log.e("ERROR", str);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    String str = response.body().toString();
                    Log.e("ERROR", "Body: "+str);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this I modified the flow and didn't use retrofit in authorization part.
I created this:

```
HttpUrl httpUrl = HttpUrl.parse("https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize");
        HttpUrl builtUrl = httpUrl.newBuilder()
                .addQueryParameter("client_id", "my client ID")
                .addQueryParameter("redirect_uri", REDIRECT_URI)
                .addQueryParameter("response_type", "token")
                .addQueryParameter("scope", "analytics:read:games")
                //.addQueryParameter("state", "asdqwe123")
                .build();
        callback.onSuccess(builtUrl.url());
```

After I create and Intent and startActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(url)));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Works like a charm.